# Show contents in Modal Popup

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 i've seen many people are using Modal Popup window to show list contents. How to achieve this in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look for information on the Dialog Framework.

This training module should help you get started: [Module 10: Creating Dialogs and Ribbon Controls for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513157)

Comment: I exactly want this. 
http://sites.gitca.org/fvspug/Lists/JobPostings/AllItems.aspx

Comment: That is a List View web part. It is available out-of-the-box.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/list-view-web-part-HA010024052.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Shapoint 2010 ECMA Script Modal Dialog:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx